# put the CupertinoTabBar down

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

I'm only using the library 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart'; to make an App... but i can't put the CupertinoTabBar down. Can someone help me? [myapp here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTfmX.png)

```
CupertinoPageScaffold(
  navigationBar: CupertinoNavigationBar(
    middle: Text("Escala NVP"),
  ),
  child: SafeArea(
    child: Container(
      child: CupertinoTabBar(
        items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(IconData(0xF38F, fontFamily: "CupertinoIcons", fontPackage: CupertinoIcons.iconFontPackage)), title: Text("Início")),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(IconData(0xF2D1, fontFamily: "CupertinoIcons", fontPackage: CupertinoIcons.iconFontPackage)), title: Text("Calendário")),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(IconData(0xF3A0, fontFamily: "CupertinoIcons", fontPackage: CupertinoIcons.iconFontPackage)), title: Text("Perfil")),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        onTap: (int index){
          setState(() {
            _selectedIndex = index;
          });
        },
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.

```
CupertinoPageScaffold(
  navigationBar: CupertinoNavigationBar(
    middle: Text("Escala NVP"),
  ),
  child: CupertinoTabScaffold(
    tabBar: CupertinoTabBar(
        items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(IconData(0xF38F, fontFamily: "CupertinoIcons", fontPackage: CupertinoIcons.iconFontPackage)), title: Text("Início")),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(IconData(0xF2D1, fontFamily: "CupertinoIcons", fontPackage: CupertinoIcons.iconFontPackage)), title: Text("Calendário")),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(IconData(0xF3A0, fontFamily: "CupertinoIcons", fontPackage: CupertinoIcons.iconFontPackage)), title: Text("Perfil")),
        ],
          currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
          onTap: (int index){
            setState(() {
              _selectedIndex = index;
            });
        },
      ),
    tabBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
      return CupertinoTabView(
        builder: (BuildContext context){
          return Container(
          );
        },
      );
    },
    ),
);
```